# How to set UIBarButtonItem with customView without losing selector

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I have a UIBarButtonItem in IB

That button has selectors.

Things work fine but I want to change the appearance.

Hence I did:

```
   UIImage * imageSetting= [UIImage imageNamed:@"setting-button"];
    UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:imageSetting];
    self.editSettings = [self.editSettings initWithCustomView:imageView];
```

Now appearance works fine but pressing the button won't get me to any code at all.

What to do?

Comment: The problem is that you have re initialized the button with the 3rd line of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
self.editSettings = [self.editSettings initWithCustomView:imageView];
```

with

```
[self.editSettings setCustomView:imageView];
```

Hope this helps you..

Answer (score 2):

After you instantiate your custom item, you need to set a target and an action on it.

e.g.

```
if(self.editSettings) // make sure it exists
{
    self.editSettings.target = self;
    self.editSettings.action = @selector(doSomething:)
}
```

(assuming you have a method named "`doSomething:`" in your view controller...

Answer (score 2):

You can have a create action method for that bar button item and then connect that action in xib you can do this programmatically also using below code:

```
self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(addtechniciansnametoplist:)];
```